# Binding TextBox.Text to custom collection does not display custom ToString()

Tags: wpf, binding, collections, textbox

I have a custom collection that extends ObservableCollection and overrides ToString().
If I binding this collection to the Text property of a TextBox like so:

```
  <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Satellites, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

where Satellites will be an instance of this custom collection, the text box displays `(Collection)` instead of calling my custom implementation of ToString().

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is probably being bound to a `CollectionView` rather than directly to the collection.

Try adding a property to the collection class to return the text to display:

```
public string DisplayText
{
   get { return ToString(); }
}
```

and then bind to that property:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Satellites.DisplayText, Mode=OneTime}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe WPF looks at type of bound object and when it sees an IEnumerable, it just won't call ToString().

But I think that you can achieve same result by using a converter (supposed that you want to bind that collection only once). Look at [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).